# How Can I assign an IP address to my virtual Windows Server, so that I can start using it almost as a VPS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines

We are a small office set up with two PC's out of which one of my PCs runs 24hrs. Its almost equivalent to a small server, but right now we're in need of a server which is why I am planning to keep my machine as well as a server into a single PC.

I've used VMware Workstation to create a powerful Windows Server 2008 within my PC and I want to attach it to my Network Switch through the same PC where I am hosting it. I want to use it almost like a physical server with an IP address and everything so that I can connect from one Pc to the Server directly or my applications can connect to Server straight with the IP address.

How should I do this?
Step by step instructions would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Best regards
Nelson

Answer (score 1):

In the VM settings make sure the Virtual NIC is using a VMWare network that is in [bridged mode](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018697).  Then give your virtual machine a static IP inside Windows like you normally would for a physical server.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_configure_ws.html

It varies slightly depending on the version of VMWare Workstation you are using, but:

- Make sure it's set up as "Bridged" and NOT "NAT" or some other setting.
- This will present your server on the network "raw" as if it was just another computer on the network, so you can set it up just as if it was a physical computer (DHCP, static IP Address, etc.)

If you move the VM to another computer, keep the same MAC address and it will just be like moving a physical computer.